# Minimizing tracking error for a 150 / 50 portfolio against the S&P500

Tags: portfolio-optimization, portfolio-management, optimization, tracking-error

I am trying to minimize tracking error ex-ante for a 150 / 50 portfolio, eg. it is 150 units long, 50 units short and market exposure of 100 units. It uses all 500 stock in the S&P500.

I've gathered 2 years of daily returns for each stock to create a correlation matrix for all 500 stocks. Now I use an optimizer to minimize the portfolio correlation given that the weights add to 100, the positives add to 150 and the negatives add to 50. Of course I add in an additional line to the correlation matrix for the index and hard code the weight at -100. So the optimizer is trying to minimize correlation between the portfolio of the 150/50 against the index.

Is this the correct approach? The reason I believe that I am doing something wrong is that the portfolio correlation will not drop below 0.25 for some reason.

Comment: I might not be understanding but, if the constraint is to be 3 more times long than short, then why would it be odd to not  be able to get less than 25 % correlation ?  Back in the pre-historic days when I worked with indices, 80% of the cap of the SAP was in like the top 75-100 stocks. So, you're going to have to be in quite a few of them so 0.25 doesn't sound terrible. But, as I said, I could be confused about what you're doing.